# cannot use Arr library in project build with androidx

Tags: android, androidx, aar

I have migrated my project to androidx. my project depends on some third party libraries, i'm using one arr file in my project. after migration, i'm getting error like below.

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed
>   to transform file 'csjsdk-beta.aar' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform Show
>   Details Affected Modules: csjsdkdemo-app

here is app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.csjbot.csjsdkdemo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            // 将 jniLib 指向 libs
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation(name: 'csjsdk-beta', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.23.Final'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}
```

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: this error might be occur because of csjsdk-beta.aar file which does not have androidx support. make sure build support should be same as your app module.

Comment: yes, it's built on android support libraries. is there any way to use this library with project based on androidx?

Comment: try this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860912/modifying-contents-of-android-aar-file-converting-to-and-from-zip-format) to modify content of aar file.

Comment: Post your app level gradle build file here.

Comment: updated description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to transform file 'some-lib-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795731/failed-to-transform-file-some-lib-release-aar-to-match-attributes-artifacttyp)

Comment: why you don't just migrate that library to androidx ??

Comment: why you are not using androidX libraries when you are using androidX project.

Comment: no i cannot migrate because i have arr file provided by company who build the sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your gradle caches which should be stored here: `C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1`, and then rebuild the project.

Edit:

Change your dependencies in `build.gradle` to use AndroidX namespace:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation(name: 'csjsdk-beta', ext: 'aar')
implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.23.Final'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

Comment: yes, i have tried this. but not working. it seems that issue occurred because arr is not built using androidx.

Comment: Yes but that's what Jetify is for. It should transform your aar to AndroidX namespace automatically. I'm 90% sure it's related to caches. Try clearing everything and invalidating caches from inside Android Studio.

Comment: Hi, I have removed transform-1 folder, then set android.enableJetifier=false in gradle.properties file, then able to build project successfully. but getting error Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
 is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 
if revert to android.enableJetifier=true, then getting same old issue

Comment: I already migrated all to androidx name space, it seems i have uploaded outdated gradle build file here when i revert androidx migration. thanks for pointing out

Comment: by deleting C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1 and rebuilding project it worked but i got another problem regarding  manifest merge

Answer (score 0):

After migrating into Android X, you need to do some steps to clear all the un-used imports.

To clear all those un-used imports :-

Right click on src:- You will get an option "Optimise imports"
Once you are done with this optimisation. Check it out all the changes in github.

If still you are getting same issue. 
Close the project. Re-import the project again.

Comment: I also faced same issue. But I follow this steps :- 1. Clone the project again. 2. Open Android Studio. 3 There is one option "Import project" import it again..