# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'. Failed to transform artifact 'tensorflow-lite-api.aar

Tags: android, tensorflow, runtime-error, tensorflow-lite

While running old project on latest android studio on tensorflow lite.
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform artifact 'tensorflow-lite-api.aar (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.10.0)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=15}
> > Execution failed for DexingTransform: C:\Users\bhanu.mahto.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\909aa36c283e1c03f5255c732f1ca9e4\jars\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by adding compileOptions in the build.gradle (app) :

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Thanks for the answer posted by :

[Failed to transform file 'some-lib-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795731/failed-to-transform-file-some-lib-release-aar-to-match-attributes-artifacttyp/57303795#57303795)

For the problem :

[Failed to transform file 'some-lib-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795731/failed-to-transform-file-some-lib-release-aar-to-match-attributes-artifacttyp)